# NSStreamを用いたソケット通信でデータの長さを指定した受信動作をしたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket

GCDAsyncSocketというライブラリを用いてソケット通信を行っていたのですが、
IPv6 only Networkでのデバッグで

```
lost connect Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=51 "Network is unreachable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Network is unreachable, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in connect() function}
```

というエラーが出てしまいどうにもいかなくなってしまったため、
NSStreamでの実装を行っているのですが、データの受信でデータが欠けるという事態に対処ができなくご教示いただけたらと思っております。

GCDAsyncSocketであれば、readDataToLengthで指定した長さのソケットを読み込むことが出来、それにより受け取るソケットのサイズを把握することができたのですが、NSStreamではそのような実装は可能なのでしょうか？

NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailableでは以下のようにしてNSDataを取得しています

```
uint8_t buffer[4096];
unsigned int len = 0;
while ([InputStream hasBytesAvailable])
{
    [InputStream getBuffer:&buffer length:&len];
    len = [InputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
    if (len > 0){

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:len];

    }
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あらかじめNバイトのメッセージが来ることがわかっていて、Nバイトreadしようとしているように推測されるのですが、そういう書き方ではうまくいかないでしょう。バッファにバイト列を読み込んで、そこからNバイト切り出すようにするのが普通だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

2行目と5行目が間違っていると思います。
まず、5行目は不要で、いきなり

```
- (NSUInteger) read:(nonnull uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)length;
```

メソッドでデータを読み出します。その際にlenのポインターを渡しているのでlenのアドレスである途轍もなく大きいバイト数まで読み出そうとしているのが原因では無いかと思います。
以下は実際に動いている、セパレーターキャラクターが来るまで1バイトずつ読み出すコードです。

```
uint8_t oneByte;
NSInteger actuallyRead = 0;
BOOL repeat = YES;
do {    // read from stream
    actuallyRead = [readStream read:&oneByte maxLength:1U];
        // check data
    switch (actuallyRead) {
        case 1:     // success normaly one byte.
            if (oneByte == '\0')
                repeat = NO;
            else
                CFDataAppendBytes(recievedData, &oneByte, actuallyRead);
            break;
        case 0:
            return;
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Error at reading stream %@ : %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [self class]);
            NSLog(@"Stream Status : %lu", [readStream streamStatus]);
            NSLog(@"Stream Error : %@", [readStream streamError]);
            return;
            break;
    }// end switch
} while (repeat);
```

Comment: 1バイトずつ読み出したらパフォーマンスがた落ちでは？

Comment: 質問者がロジックを求めているのではなく、確実に動く方法論を求めていると判断して、サンプルとして例示しました。
まずは確実に動いているコードをと思いまして例に挙げました。
 実際はまとめてバッファーに読んで終端処理を行いますが、それは動くことを確認してからmaxLengthのパラメーターを変えて、バッファ処理を追加すれば良い問題だと思います